# Excel в Android

Tags: android, apache

На сайте апач нашел градл либы

`compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.14'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.14'`

---

Код МАИН

```
       try {

        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(getAssets().open("data.xls"));

        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        Row row = sheet.getRow(1);

        Cell name = row.getCell(0);
        Cell age = row.getCell(1);

        Log.d("", name.getStringCellValue() + " " + age.getNumericCellValue());

    } catch(Exception ex) {
        return;
    }
```

---

Код ошибки

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Вот весь код ошибки
http://pastebin.com/gGL1CtCB

Что означает ошибка и как мне бытЬ?

Comment: там выше в логе должно быть больше инфы, посмотрите внимательнее

Comment: @metalurgus, ок выложил. только там вроде простой текст. А не сама ошибка.... Хотя не знаю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка выглядит следующим образом:

> trouble processing "javax/xml/XMLConstants.class": Ill-advised or
>   mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) when not building a
>   core library.

Это значит, что библиотека содержит классы, которые находятся в пакетах `javax.*` или `java.*`, и является расширением JDK. (`Core library`).
Что это значит для вас:
Скорее всего эту библиотеку невозможно использовать в Android.
Если вы все же хотите попробовать, то можете отредактировать файл `dx.bat`, который отвечает за сборку прилодения. В последнюю строку файла перед `%params%` нужно добавить параметр `--core-library`, что разрешит компиляцию `core-library`. После этого последняя строка должна выглядеть примерно так:

```
call "%java_exe%" %javaOpts% -Djava.ext.dirs="%frameworkdir%" -jar "%jarpath%" --core-library %params%
```

Файл `dx.bat` находится в папке `android-sdk\build-tools\<версия build-tools, которую вы используете>`.

Comment: http://dajver.blogspot.ru/2014/02/ms-excel-android.html

Comment: @xTIGRx, и...? Что мне с этим делать?

Comment: @xTIGRx, Если вы пытаетесь следовать инструкции в статье, то попробуйте придерживаться ее как минимум полностью. Кроме того, там есть ссылка на исходники, которые вы можете скачать

Comment: дак там такая же ошибка

Comment: надо было прописать манифест